# display data added by user in sessions using leftjoin

Tags: php, mysql

i have managed to create a form whereby the user logs in using sessions and once the user is logged in ,he/she is able to post data into a different table named members.My problem is that I'm unable to retrieve the data added by the logged in user from the members table.I'm a newbie and i hope someone here will help me figure out this.below is my code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['phone'])){
 header("location: login2.php");
 }
else {
include ("../includes/db.php");

$sql = "select * FROM post";
$run = mysql_query($sql);
$total_post=mysql_num_rows($run);

$sql = "select * FROM gallary";
$run = mysql_query($sql);
$total_image=mysql_num_rows($run);

$sql = "select * FROM user";
$run = mysql_query($sql);
$total_user=mysql_num_rows($run);

$sql = "select * FROM course";
$run = mysql_query($sql);
$total_course=mysql_num_rows($run);

$sql = "select * FROM mails";
$run = mysql_query($sql);
$total_mails=mysql_num_rows($run);
?>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Dashboard</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- MetisMenu CSS -->
    <link href="../bower_components/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Timeline CSS -->
    <link href="../dist/css/timeline.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="../dist/css/sb-admin-2.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Morris Charts CSS -->
    <link href="../bower_components/morrisjs/morris.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="../bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


</head>

<body>

    <div id="wrapper">

        <!-- Navigation -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation" style="margin-bottom: 0">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">Dashboard</a>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-header -->

            <ul class="nav navbar-top-links navbar-right">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i>  <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-user">
                        
                        <li><a href="logout.php"><i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-fw"></i> Logout</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- /.dropdown-user -->
                </li>
                <!-- /.dropdown -->
            </ul>
            <!-- /.navbar-top-links -->

            <div class="navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation">
                <div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
                       
                        <li>
                            <a href="index2.php"><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw"></i> Dashboard</a>
                        </li>
                        <!--
                        <li>
                            <a href="new_post.php"><i class="fa fa-edit fa-fw"></i> Create New Post</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="index.php?view_post=view_post"><i class="fa fa-table fa-fw"></i> View All Post</a>
                        </li>
       <li>
                            <a href="new_course.php"><i class="fa fa-edit fa-fw"></i> Create New Story</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="course.php"><i class="fa fa-table fa-fw"></i> View All Story</a>
                        </li>
      
                        <li>
                            <a href="new_images.php"><i class="fa fa-edit fa-fw"></i> Upload Image</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="images.php"><i class="fa fa-photo fa-fw"></i> View All Image</span></a>
                        </li>
                         <li>
                            <a href="mails.php"><i class="fa fa-photo fa-fw"></i> View All emails</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="members.php"><i class="fa fa-edit fa-fw"></i> View All Joining members</span></a>
                        </li>
                              -->                 
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- /.sidebar-collapse -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-static-side -->
        </nav>

        <div id="page-wrapper">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <h1 class="page-header">Dashboard</h1>
                </div>
                <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.row -->
      <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
                    <div class="panel panel-primary">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-3">
                                    <i class="fa fa-list-ul fa-5x"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-9 text-right">
                                    <div class="huge"><?php echo $total_post; ?></div>
                                    <div>All Posts!</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <a href="index.php?view_post=view_post">
                            <div class="panel-footer">
                                <span class="pull-left">View Details</span>
                                <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></span>
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
                    <div class="panel panel-green">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-3">
                                    <i class="fa fa-photo fa-5x"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-9 text-right">
                                    <div class="huge"><?php echo $total_image; ?></div>
                                    <div>All Images!</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <a href="images.php">
                            <div class="panel-footer">
                                <span class="pull-left">View Details</span>
                                <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></span>
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
                    <div class="panel panel-yellow">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-3">
                                    <i class="fa fa-users fa-5x"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-9 text-right">
                                    <div class="huge"><?php echo $total_user; ?></div>
                                    <div>All Users!</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <a href="users.php">
                            <div class="panel-footer">
                                <span class="pull-left">View Details</span>
                                <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></span>
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
                    <div class="panel panel-red">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-3">
                                    <i class="fa fa-database fa-5x"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-9 text-right">
                                    <div class="huge"><?php echo $total_course; ?></div>
                                    <div>All Story!</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <a href="course.php">
                            <div class="panel-footer">
                                <span class="pull-left">View Details</span>
                                <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></span>
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                 <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
                    <div class="panel panel-yellow">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-3">
                                    <i class="fa fa-database fa-5x"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-9 text-right">
                                    <div class="huge"><?php echo $total_mails; ?></div>
                                    <div>All mails!</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <a href="mails.php">
                            <div class="panel-footer">
                                <span class="pull-left">View Details</span>
                                <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></span>
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            
        

<!--Post Section Open-->

<div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
 <div class="panel-heading">
  <h2>All users</h2>
 </div>
 <div class="panel-body">
 <div class="dataTable_wrapper">
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
   <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>S.No.</th>
                <th>Id</th>
        <th>First_name</th>
                        <th>Last NAme</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                                    <th>phone</th>
                                        <th>created</th>
                                            <th>modified</th>
                                             <th>status</th>               
                                     <th>Edit</th>
                                     <th>Delete</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>


 <?php
include("../includes/db.php");
$i=1;

$query="SELECT members.user_id,members.name,members.phone,members.location, user.username,user.phone
FROM members
LEFT JOIN user
ON members.user_id=user.phone
ORDER BY members.user_id;"
   
?>





 
 <?php } ?>
                                            
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <!--Post Section Close-->


                        </div>
                        <!-- /#page-wrapper -->

                    </div>
                    <!-- /#wrapper -->

                    <!-- jQuery -->
                    <script src="../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>

                    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
                    <script src="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

                    <!-- Metis Menu Plugin JavaScript -->
                    <script src="../bower_components/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.js"></script>

                    <!--  Charts JavaScript -->
                    <script src="../bower_components/raphael/raphael-min.js"></script>
                    <script src="../bower_components/morrisjs/morris.min.js"></script>
                    <script src="../js/morris-data.js"></script>

                    <!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
                    <script src="../dist/js/sb-admin-2.js"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must join table with valid condition. I don't know your table structure for user table, as a guess i think this will help you.

```
$query="SELECT members.user_id,members.name,members.phone,members.location,
user.username,user.phone, user.id
FROM members
LEFT JOIN user
ON members.user_id=user.id
ORDER BY members.user_id;"
```

Comment: and how do i display the data ,on the page ,thats my big problem because i get an error once i run the query

Comment: displaying the data i.e ,if i use a while loop ,an error comes

Comment: my user table has these columns: user_id,user_name,pass,location,email &phone  and my members table has this columns :id,user_id,name,location,phone,datejoined,age and gender. so the user logs in  using phone and pass then the logged user adds data to the members table where the phone stored in a session is added to  the members table in User_id column but now i cant retrieve the data